# How to scrape dynamic content with Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, scrapy

I would like to scrape some interest rates. I need to use Selenium to access dynamically loaded content. For the Selenium part, the following works fine:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from scrapy.selector import Selector

chromedriver = "/usr/local/bin/chromedriver"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)

driver.get("http://www.infochoice.com.au/banking/savings-account/term-deposit-interest-rates.aspx")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@name='SavingsTerm']/option[text()='7 days']").click()
```

Now I would like to parse the html content to get the interest rates using something like:

```
xpath("//*[@id='IC_ProductList107Rate']/table/tbody/tr[5]/td/text()").extract()
```

It should be very easy, however I am new to Python and could not figure out a suitable procedure so far.

How can this be implemented?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if I understand very well but you can try with this:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='IC_ProductList107Rate']/table/tbody/tr[5]/td/text()").text
```

or

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='IC_ProductList107Rate']/table/tbody/tr[5]/td/text()").get_attribute(element_attribute_value)
```

element_attribute_value can be 'value', 'text' etc... depend which attrbute you have in your HTML code

Comment: Thanks! With slight modification of your first suggestion, it works.